# simple div css centering content in the middle

Tags: css, html, center, footer

hey im a css newbie but i know this should be easy. if someone could help me really quick so i could stop breaking my head trying to figure this out thatd be great.

only have 2 items i need help placing.

one 400x200px image that i always want in the center (both vertically and horizontally) thatll be the content. 
and 
one line of text that i want centered at the bottom thatll be the footer.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more specific to get responses.  Eg. what do you want your image to be in the center of? .. the page?  a div?  Same for the text.  And is that all that's on the page, or are there other items?

Comment: You should provide the code you're currently using that isn't working.

Comment: can you put up what you've tried and the screenshots(if possible)

Comment: In the center of what? The page? A container? If the later, are the container's width and height fixed, or will they need to expand/contract to accommodate varying content or viewport width or the container's parent width? Do you need to have text or other items "flow" around this image, or is it an overlay like a light-box? Your answer would depend on all of these considerations.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses. i dont want anything on the page other than the image and the footer so its pretty basic. just the image in the center both horizontally and vertically and the footer at the bottom. thats it. i guess the part im struggling with is to have the image centered and the footer at the bottom regardless of what screen resolution is being used.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand what your asking i think you should try this using margins within css really is the way to go. ;)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Center</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            IMG.image1 {
                position: absolute;
                left: 50%;
                top: 50%;
                margin-left: -200px;
                margin-top: -100px
            }
            #footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="Centeredcontent">    
            <img class="image1" width="400px" height="200px"></img>
        </div>
            <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

what ever your total image height and width is by half and make it negative, so for width it would be (margin-left: -200px;) and for top it would be (margin-right: -100px;)

Comment: #footer could be postion:absolute or position:fixed. Either way should work fine.

Comment: all this is accomplishing is centering the image horizontally. same function as <center>.

Comment: fixed understand what your saying now :D

Comment: First time I've ever seen someone use uppercase tag names in css.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a concept of vertical centering in CSS. It's been a long time gripe. Options:

- You could use a table. I find this an OK use of one for positioning.
- You could use JavaScript. Get the height of the window, do some math, then position the image. A little messy. Maybe more effort than its worth.
- You could use display: table CSS. Alas, doesn't work in IE AFAIK.
- You could just fake it. Give the image a top margin of 150px and be OK with the bottom space being variable. That's the route I'd go. Pragmatic design. ;)